# How add sliding window on flex charts?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

How to add sliding window on charts in flex.when we move window on the chart ,chart data of behind the area of the window will appear in another chart .

Comment: This link will helps to solve above problem.thank you :)

[Sliding window on column chart in flex ][1]


  [1]: http://erangap.blogspot.com/2013/10/sliding-window-on-column-chart-in-flex.html